# What is a good analogy for electric potential?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, potential-energy, voltage

When the electrical field was defined I could totally relate to $\vec{E}$ being like $\vec{g}$ in mechanics.

But for the electric potential I don't know what would be equivalent analogy. Any suggestions?

Comment: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/397736/45664

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question. But if you have no problem relating electric field with gravitational field what's the problem relating electrostatic potential with gravitational potential?